# Modify relationship chains in Neo4j with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created erroneous relationships in my production database and need to update the relationships in order to correct the issue - this is it:

I have a function in my application which allows a user to copy a node (original node). When a user copies a node a relationship is created between the original and the copy. The error came in when a copy was copied. A relationship should have been created from the second copy back to the first original node but instead it was created between copy 1 and copy 2:

```
(Original)-->(Copy1)-->(Copy2)-->(Copy3) ... etc
```

this should have been:

```
            (Copy2)
               ^
               |
(Copy3)<--(Original)-->(Copy1)
```

How can I update the relationship chain to point back to the original?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a little example since I don't know your specific data model. Given the following scenaro in your graph database:

```
CREATE (original:Thing)-[:HAS_COPY]->(copy1:Thing)-[:HAS_COPY]->(copy2:Thing)-[:HAS_COPY]->(copy3:Thing)
```

It is possible to collect this chain of copies around the node starting the chain:

```
MATCH (copy:Thing)<-[rels:HAS_COPY*]-(original)
WHERE NOT ()-[:HAS_COPY]->(original)
FOREACH (r IN rels | DELETE r)
CREATE (original)-[:HAS_COPY]->(copy)
```

Here we match each copy that is connected to the original through an arbitrary number of `HAS_COPY` relations (`*`). The original node we know because it self is not a copy of anything. Then, for each of the relations between the copy and it's original we delete them and create a new òne directly to the original.

I have tested this a little bit, and it should work well, but please do test it before applying it to your production database.

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly. my relationships were in the other direction, so I just reversed the arrows.